# Why if I map a new array of strings it resort the items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

So I have these 2 maps:

```js
const fieldsIds = fields?.length ? fields.map(f => f.id) : []
const renderFields = questions.filter(q => fieldsIds.includes(q.id))
```

That second map is resorting the array. For example the first map (fieldsIds) returns this which is ok:

[image]

But the second map (renderFields) returns what you will see in the screenshot even if I push first the last id `9ckmhbxq6m00003f665yocii9` which starts with the highest number, it will be resort to be the last one.

[image]

I mean, if I push the ids on this order:
`7ckmhbxq6m00003f665yocii9`, `5ckmhbxq6m00003f665yocii9`, `9ckmhbxq6m00003f665yocii9` and `2ckmhbxq6m00003f665yocii9`, they will be resort it in the second array to:
`2ckmhbxq6m00003f665yocii9`, `5ckmhbxq6m00003f665yocii9`, `7ckmhbxq6m00003f665yocii9` and `9ckmhbxq6m00003f665yocii9`.

Do you get it?

Any ideas what is this happening? I need to avoid that (alphanumeric) resorting.

Comment: Please provide sample data as text.

Comment: Your `questions` and `fields` are different arrays. Are you sure they are in the same order? Doesn't seem like it.

Comment: You refer to your 'second map' but it's a filter. You can't sort with a filter. Filters just return an item if their return value is truthy

Comment: It looks like what you actually want is `const questionsById = new Map(questions.map(q => [q.id, q])); const renderFields = fields?.map(f => questionsById.get(f.id)) ?? [];`